# VueJS: can't pass file to method from generated list

Tags: javascript

I have  list of inputs and labels that are generated with a `v-for`.  when i flight tested this with ONE item, it worked.  when i expanded it for dynamicism, it broke all to !@#$.  please point out my error.

here's my HTML:

```html
<div v-for="(dRow, dIndex) in modalRows">
  <section v-if="!dRow.isComplete">
    <label :for="('proof' + dIndex)"><b>PROOF</b> (pdf, jpg, png):
      <input type="file" :id="('proof' + dIndex)" ref="file" 
             @change="handleFileUpload(this.('proof' + dIndex))" />
    </label>
    <i class="las la-upload uploader" 
       @click.prevent="uploadProof(('proof' + dIndex).file, dRow)"></i>
  </section>
</div>
```

and here's my Vue methods: (literally just checking if anything made it through)

```js
handleFileUpload(file){ console.log(file); }
uploadProof(file,dRow){ console.log(file); console.log(dRow); }
```

it used to output the `files` array when i had only one item manually id'd and labelled.  now that i've altered it to allow for array-driven lists of inputs, it just reports:

> invalid expression: missing name after . operator in handleFileUpload(this.('proof' + dIndex))

i'm at a loss.  where's my mistake and what the !@#$ does that error mean???

Comment: I think you want `this['proof' + dIndex]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: If I'm reading your code right, rather than have a bunch of properties like `proof0`, `proof1`, etc you should really have an array, ie `proof: []`. It would make accessing each element much easier

Comment: FFS.  i keep forgetting that `this` now refers to `Window`, not the element that calls the method.  @Phil you are correct.  that did it.  thank you.  i'm going to tattoo this on the back of my hands....  >:(

Comment: In Vue, `this` typically refers to your component, not `window`. Your issue was a basic JavaScript syntax error. Nothing to do with Vue

Comment: the reason i don't use an array, is that these can be triggered non-sequentially and it saves my having to figure out which place in the array their file is.  sometimes, nothing will be selected/uploaded, but other portions of the list will.  to my mind, it seemed an easier solve than an array (which i did consider) for pure simplicity in this context.  i am, however, happy to be wrong and learn a better way though.